# Copying files to dropbox via ssh results in a wrong file size

Tags: ssh, dropbox

Not really sure about the nature of the problem.

I ssh to a remote machine. Issue a

```
cd ~/Dropbox
cp -r ~/Documents .
```

and getting messages of

> No such file or directory

for specific files during the copy.

Also I seem to be getting different file sizes for the two folders,

```
du -s ~/Documents/
7894448 /Users/cue/Documents/
```

with the one in dropbox being larger

```
du -s ~/Dropbox/Documents
7974480 /Users/cue/Dropbox/Documents
```

The source folder is on MacOSX if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be files with names that don't agree with Dropbox or that aren't handled properly by the unix shell cp command?

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS still uses resource forks in some cases.  OS X comes with a copying tool called [ditto](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html) that helps with copying those files.

> ditto will preserve resource forks and
>   HFS meta-data information when copying
>   unless instructed otherwise using
>   --norsrc.